# How to run a siddhi app in WSO2 stream processor without editor (Using worker container in Docker)

Tags: docker, containers, worker, wso2-streaming-integrator

My requirement is to run siddhi apps in WSO2 stream processor for a production setup using docker containers void of editor. I want to deploy and run siddhi apps using docker run command while bringing up the worker container.

We do not want to have a editor setup as part of our production environment please let us know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wso2sp-worker[1] image and have a volume mount to the hot-deployment directory and start the worker runtime. Use the below command to run the docker based worker runtime. When the runtime starts, it will deploy the apps within the deployment directory.

```
docker run -it -v <local-siddhi-app-dir>:/home/wso2carbon/wso2sp-4.4.0/wso2/worker/deployment/siddhi-files docker.wso2.com/wso2sp-worker:4.4.0
```

**Note:** In order to use Docker images with WSO2 updates, you need an active WSO2 subscription. If you do not possess an active WSO2 subscription, you can sign up for a WSO2 Free Trial Subscription from [here](https://wso2.com/free-trial-subscription). Otherwise, you can proceed with Docker images which are created using GA releases.

Furthermore, Siddhi is the streaming engine that runs the streaming logic within the WSO2 Stream Processor. With Siddhi 5.0.0 release, it plays as a Cloud-native Stream Processor. Refer to the Siddhi official documentation for further details [2].

[1] http://docker.wso2.com/tags.php?repo=wso2sp-worker
[2] https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi/